# autosuggestbox for listview items

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, autosuggest

I have made a listview in my app and I wants to add searchbar for it. I have gone over many forums but cnt get it. I knw I have to use `AutoSuggestBox` but don't get the correct method. Here is my code hope someone can help over it..

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Padding="15,0,0,0">
            <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" TextChanged="autosuggesttextchanged" QuerySubmitted="autosuggestquerysubmitted" SuggestionChosen="autosuggestsuggestionchosen"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource herolistview}}" ItemClick="itemclicked" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,4">
                            <Image Height="50" Width="88" Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Padding="8,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding key}' FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

.cs file

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<mainpageclass> hlist = new ObservableCollection<mainpageclass>();


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Filldata();
    }
    void Filldata()
    {
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "Aba" });
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "Al" });
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "Anon" });
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "An"});
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "Aren" });
        hlist.Add(new mainpageclass { name = "Boe"});
        list.ItemsSource = hlist;
    }

    private void autosuggesttextchanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {

        }
    }

    private void autosuggestquerysubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    private void autosuggestsuggestionchosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't test your code right now. Try to write code inside the method autosuggesttextchanged, performing your search inside the hlist ObservableCollection. This collection is the datasource of your ListView, so if you filter using LINQ, the ListView updates itself with the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private void autosuggesttextchanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            var filtered = hlist.Where(i => i.name.Contains(this.box.Text)).ToList();
            list.ItemsSource = filtered;
        }
    }
```

Please note that I need to set a name for the AutoSuggestBox (x:Name="box"). And note that the XAML : ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource herolistview}}" is useless, because from the code-behind you overwrite the ItemsSource property! :-)

Comment: although it worked but there is problem in it, when I m typing a letter in autosuggestbox listview is updated with the letter entered but it is not updating as per the first letter means like if I type 'f' then listview is not updating with the items starting with 'f' instead with the items in which there is 'f' letter in the whole item. I can't direct excess the word starting with 'f'

Comment: it worked on my phone properly. thnx man. I think I have to uninstall the app on the pc and then deploy on it.